# How to add left , center and right background in menu item?

Tags: css, html

I am creating menu using css and have three background stripes ( left, center & right) to display. I can add only one background for 'li'. How can I add others?

Comment: Can't you make them into one image and set that as the <li>'s bg image?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple background images are not supported in CSS 2.  If you need to have separate background images, you'll have to add some additional markup for them. e.g.

Instead of:

```
<li>item</li>
```

You'll need

```
<li><span><span>item</span></span></li>
```

Ugly, I know.  Your other option would be to combine the images.